# Remove items in an array that are contained in other items [Python]

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, macos, sorting

I'm not sure if the title is a great explanation of what I'm trying to do so here is an example:

```
Array = ['orangutan', 'sun', 'tan']
```

I want to print:

```
'orangutan', 'sun'
```

I've tried looping through the array and looking to see if one item contains another item as followed:

```
for i in Array:
remove_duplicates = [x for x in Array if x in i]
```

But this hasn't worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
result = [x
          for i, x in enumerate(Array)
          if all(x not in y for j, y in enumerate(Array) if i != j)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
lst = ['orangutan', 'sun', 'tan']

print([x for i, x in enumerate(lst)
       if not any(x in y for j, y in enumerate(lst) if i != j)])
```

**Update:**

It won't escape notice that I have arrived at essentially the same solution as Riccardo Bucco. But the tests are different here. For the equivalence of these two tests, see [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).  The `any` (i.e. a reduction of `or` over the boolean inputs) gives the *inverse* of `all` (i.e. reduction of `and`) on the *inverse* of those inputs -- hence the `not any(... in ...)` is equivalent to `all(... not in ...)`.

In either case, iteration will stop at the first match: `all` will stop iterating and return `False` if it sees a false-like value, and `any` will stop iterating and return `True` if it sees a true-like value.

Comment: Same as my answer :)

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Looks like we both did the obvious thing (obviously independently - they were seconds apart). But we have slightly different tests. I wonder if it is useful to leave them both up?

Comment: Yes yes I don't mind, I did not want to remove yours, it's just funny that we used even the same names for variables :D

Comment: @RiccardoBucco They were the obvious choices.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Added some explanation of why I think it is useful to see these two side by side.

Comment: Thanks, great!! It's indeed very important NOT to use a list within `any` and `all` so that the iteration stops as soon as it encounters a `False` value. Upvote for the useful comment!

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Yes, clearly a generator expression is the right thing here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have another array with the strings that you want to keep.
If this is the case, you can loop and use .pop():

```
array=['orangutan', 'sun', 'tan']
other_array=['orangutan', 'sun']
for i in range(0,len(array)):
    if array[i] not in other_array:
        array.pop(i)
        
print(array)
```

array=['orangutan', 'sun']

Comment: By the title I understand that what he has is a list of the ones he wants to remove (`other_array = ['tan']`) and therefore you would also need to remove the `not` in the conditional.

Comment: Yes, in that case it is as simple as adding that small change

Answer (score 0):

The remove() method removes the first matching element (which is passed as an argument) from the list.

Comment: list.remove(element)

Comment: Please modify your answer instead of adding it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried looping through the array and looking to see if one item contains another item as followed.

you were almost there:

```py
list_ = []
Array = ['orangutan', 'sun', 'tan']
for i in Array:
    list_.extend([x for x in Array if x in i and x != i])
print(list_)
```

output:

```py
['tan']
```